# Getting wrong GEO Location - How can I fix it?

Tags: internet, ip, geolocation

So I did multiple ip searches on multiple websites and the Geographical location is Sri Lanka. It shows IPS is DataShack, LC

The real location should be Kansas City, MO. USA My server's ip is 199.168.103.234 or play.fluixstudios.com

We are renting the server from www.wholesaleinternet.net

How can I make sure the geo-location is correct?

Comment: What is the actual question? How do you correct it?

Comment: So the question is how can I correct the location of my server to show correct one.

Comment: The other thing I'd be asking myself is whether the server I am paying WholesaleInternet.net for is actually in Kansas City.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to correct it is to find what third-party is supplying the information to the sites you are checking and have them fix it.

For example, whatismyip.com has a [page](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-geolocation-incorrect/) listing the third-parties they use with links on how to contact them.